# Is there a Windows Live Messenger client for Facebook or the RockMelt browser?

Tags: facebook, windows-live-messenger

Is there a client or application for Facebook that allow me to talk to the [MSN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSN) contacts?

If not, is there one for the [RockMelt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RockMelt) browser?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third party client, such as [Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/) or [Adium](http://adium.im/). Otherwise, as far as I know, the integration is the other way around - from Live to Facebook: http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/coolstuff/Windows-Live-Messenger-Now-Supports-Facebook-Chat